# DLNA vs (RTSP & UPNP & Webservices) for a media server implementation

Tags: web-services, rtsp, upnp, dlna

Hello I'm a little confused about DLNA which seems a very complex thing
against one solution like putting together RTSP & UPNP & Webservices( for implementing a Content directory service)...why DLNA is still in use?

Answer (score 1):

DLNA is not a technology, it's a set of guidelines, certification infrastructure and a test suite for UPnP A/V products. So DLNA is in use because manufacturers want to certify that e.g. their ContentDirectory service works like it should. It is in a way an admission that the UPnP spec and test suite were woefully inadequate for ensuring UPnP A/V interoperability.